# Android app made of apps (android-maven)

Tags: android, maven

I would like to have a little bit of information before starting a new android project. I have read that the android-maven plugin works nice and smooth... Is that true?
And more important, what are its possibilities? I have something in mind.

Let's say I want a modular application. Thus, I want an app made of apps (all of them android-maven). Imagine I have an app for log in in some server, an app that connects to a service1 to get some information and another one that gets information from another service2.

Can I create three individual apps (log in, service1 and service2) and then use them as a dependency on a container maven app?

Is is worth it?

Thx! E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is great project management and build tool, and can be used to build android applications with proper plugin ( maven-android-plugin IIRE provides apk packaging )

But you do not build PAK from another apks, but plain java jars -  zou can tap whateveryou like form wast maven repository of jars but have to keep in mind that  not every java jar or framework is usefull, makes sense , or will run on android.

There is no such thing as "container app" on android -  but you can define dependencies 
to other apps and android library porjects. And applications can (and should) communicate via intents and exported services.